# Is there is a function that checks if a menu page is loaded in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I created a menu to wordpress dashboard

```
add_menu_page( __('locations'), __('Locations'), 'manage_options', 'manage-locationss', 'locations_page');

function locations_page() {
    require_once(locations.php);
}
```

I want to add a style sheet to this page only , Is there is a function that cheks if this page is opened then loads a style sheet , Like this function `is_page_template()`.

Or I have to add the css using `wp_enqueue_style()` without any checks?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you try to achieve, you need something like that

```
if(is_page( 'location' )){ //  your name of your page
  wp_enqueue_style() // do stuff with you right parameters and files
}
```

`if(is_page( 'location' )){}` // Checks  if the Page with a post_title of "Location" is being displayed. In this way You can Check whatever page you need.

Comment: I want to check if I opened this menu page , I'm not sure what this function does but I don't want to check if this page exist or not , I want to check I'm viewing the page

Comment: The above code does check to see if that is the page you are currently one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP Screen and get_current_screen():

```
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $current_screen->id === 'location' ) {
    // Your code
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen